# Tensorflow Error "TypeError: Tensors in list passed to 'values' of 'Pack' Op have types [int32, int64, int32, int32, int32] that don't all match."

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, ordereddict

I am new to Tensorflow and Keras. I have loaded a dataset from CSV and created a train_dataset as such:

```
column_names = ['a', 'date', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
label_name = column_names[0]
feature_names = column_names[1:]
class_names = ['good', 'bad']

train_dataset = tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset(
    train_dataset_fp,
    batch_size,
    column_names=column_names,
    label_name=label_name,
    num_epochs=1)

features, labels = next(iter(train_dataset))
print(features)
```

My features are an OrderedDict and print as:

OrderedDict([('b', <tf.Tensor: shape=(32,), dtype=int32, numpy=
array([1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], dtype=int32)>), ('date', <tf.Tensor: shape=(32,), dtype=int64, numpy=
array([-9223372036855,  1262478794000,  1262426153000,  1262431717000,
1262425334000,  1262588520000,  1262425515000,  1262418072000,
1262420797000,  1262428601000,  1262590037000,  1262421322000,
1262433023000,  1262390762000,  1262590200000,  1262432769000,
1262427397000, -9223372036855,  1262425996000,  1262430050000,
1262431867000,  1262424427000,  1262420906000,  1262391208000,
1262590114000, -9223372036855,  1262589645000,  1262424306000,
1262428178000,  1262421300000,  1262423456000,  1262515569000])>), ('d', <tf.Tensor: shape=(32,), dtype=int32, numpy=
array([357, 313, 557, 691, 292, 557, 605, 605,  48, 295,  81, 656, 321,
734, 584, 652, 575, 465,  71, 453, 196,  48, 689, 591, 676, 271,
67, 229, 740, 713, 230, 664], dtype=int32)>), ('e', <tf.Tensor: shape=(32,), dtype=int32, numpy=
array([519, 537, 610, 178, 552, 610, 240, 240, 343, 643, 481, 340, 362,
143, 511, 167,   5, 685, 436, 105, 659, 343, 427, 242,  30, 717,
531, 492, 433, 452, 645, 303], dtype=int32)>), ('f', <tf.Tensor: shape=(32,), dtype=int32, numpy=
array([ 345,  545, 1663, 1426, 2065, 1017, 1655,   47, 2070,   -1, 1191,
191, 1569,  547, 1295, 1776, 1620,  680, 1990, 1642, 1930, 1465,
1887, 2128,  999,  447,  844, 1851, 1586, 1742, 2079,  729],
dtype=int32)>)])

As you can see one of them has dtype=int64. I then use the following function to pack the features into an array:

```
def pack_features_vector(features, labels):
  features = tf.stack(list(features.values()), axis=1)
  return features, labels
```

However when I run it:

```
train_dataset = train_dataset.map(pack_features_vector)
```

I get the following error:

"TypeError: Tensors in list passed to 'values' of 'Pack' Op have types [int32, int64, int32, int32, int32] that don't all match."

I understand that the issue is the stack function. I have an epoch format date as my second feature which was read in as int64. I think it may be easiest to convert all tensors to the same dType but I am not sure how. I can see that features collection is an OrderedDict of Numpy arrays but I do not know how to change dType of the items. I tried the following, it did not yeild a traceback but when I printed my features again all dtypes were still the same:

```
for k,v in train_dataset:
  tf.dtypes.cast(v, tf.int64)
```

I would greatly appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: This might help: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/cast

Comment: Thank you. I saw that. But to be frank, I was not sure what my arguments are. The entire collection? A single tensor? How do I denote a tensor?

Comment: Well, I cannot reproduce your error, which makes it hard to say, ([related](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)), but based on where the error occurs, your tensor with not matching datatypes is `pack_features_vector`, so I'd try `tf.dtypes.cast(pack_features_vector, tf.int32)`

Comment: Thank you @zabop. I think the issue is I cannot pack my features because of inconsistent dtypes. So I would not be able to cast anything to the pack as I would get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have figured it out. I needed to add column_defaults:

```
column_names = ['a', 'b', 'date', 'd', 'e', 'f']
column_defaults=[tf.int64, tf.int64, tf.int64, tf.int64, tf.int64, tf.int64]
label_name = column_names[0]
feature_names = column_names[1:]
class_names = ['good', 'bad']

batch_size = 32

train_dataset = tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset(
    train_dataset_fp,
    batch_size,
    column_names=column_names,
    column_defaults=column_defaults,
    label_name=label_name,
    num_epochs=1)

features, labels = next(iter(train_dataset))

def pack_features_vector(features, labels):
  features = tf.stack(list(features.values()), axis=1)
  return features, labels

train_dataset = train_dataset.map(pack_features_vector)
```

But I am now trying to create a model and predictions:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu, input_shape=(5,)),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(2)
])

predictions = model(features)
```

And get "KeyError: 'dense_input'", not sure why.